# Apple Maps for iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I'm interested in using Apple Maps for an iOS app, and have a couple of questions about it.

Is there any cost associated with using Apple Maps? Is it free, or does it depend on the type of use?
Does Apple Maps have the ability to run predefined queries based on device location? (nearby attractions, for example).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any cost associated with using Apple Maps? Is it free, or does it depend on the type of use?

It's free to use within a map view in your iOS app, in any way.

> Does Apple Maps have the ability to run predefined queries based on device location? (nearby attractions, for example).

Yes. Implementation is off-topic here.